# How to do this vertically in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to use following feature vertically in Windows 7 (Two windows vertically)?

That means,

Currently it displays both windows 100% heights and 50% width.

I need to display both windows 50% heights and 100% width.

[image: Please check screenshot]

Comment: Widows+left button?

Comment: Tile windows vertically

Comment: @MátéJuhász It will give the  100% heights and 50% width as my screenshot. I need  both windows 50% heights and 100% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open more than one window and the option is within Windows 7:

- Open the windows you need to Tile
- Right click on an empty space on **TaskBar**
- Choose from menu Tile Windows Vertically

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sam. but I did not see option to "Choose from menu Tile Windows Vertically".... I have opened multiple windows and click the right click. I don't know that I click the wrong place....

Comment: where you have the start menu it is called Task Bar on an empty space on it right click to see Tile Windows...

Comment: If you cannot use the above take a look at [Tile windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11073/stupid-geek-tricks-tile-or-cascade-multiple-windows-in-windows-7/)

Comment: on the empty space not on a minimized window, you have at the end near the clock